# Filter array of objects by other array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have next arrays:

```
let arr1 = [{id: 1, type: 'a', size: 12},{id: 2, type: 'b', size: 13},{id: 3, type: 'c', size: 14}];
let arr2 = [{id: 1, type: 'a'},{id: 2, type: 'b'}];
```

what I need that is to filter arr1 by arr2 with the same id's.
expected result:

```
[{id: 1, type: 'a', size: 12},{id: 2, type: 'b', size: 13}];
```

Comment: Does the [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method help you?

Comment: You can use hashmap  or use Collection set based on id. It will not accept duplicate and you can easily get your result

Comment: actually this is a known problem you can search on intersection of two arrays in js

Answer (score 1):

You could use `includes`

```js
let arr1 = [
  { id: 1, type: "a", size: 12 },
  { id: 2, type: "b", size: 13 },
  { id: 3, type: "c", size: 14 },
]
let arr2 = [
  { id: 1, type: "a" },
  { id: 2, type: "b" },
]

const res = arr1.filter((el1) => arr2.map((el2) => el2.id).includes(el1.id))

console.log(res)
```